# Updating ubuntu 18.04 upgradetool http issue

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I'm currently trying to upgrade a server running ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS to 20.04.6 LTS using the `do-release-upgrade` tool. I've run into an issue, where after much digging, I noticed in the file `/var/lib/update-manager/meta-release-lts` the urls held in that file are all `http`, e.g. UpgradeTool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/focal.tar.gz
my firewall can not/will not allow the server access to port 80 (`http`) but 443 (`https`) it can.

So I thought changing the contents of the file to `https` would work, however the next time you run `do-release-upgrade` it overwrites that file, but on top of that the files its trying to retrieve are actually only hosted on `http` not `https`, if you try to manually go to the location changing the url to `https` it fails.

Any alternatives or workarounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to unblock port 80 for the duration of the upgrade.

Alternatively you could run a webserver hosting the files the upgrade tool needs, and modify either `/etc/hosts` to point `archive.ubuntu.com` to your internal host.

Another, more time and resource consuming option would be to host a mirror of the Ubuntu archive internally on your network. Then as with the previous answer, point the server at the internal mirror. There are tools like `debmirror` which can mirror the entire Ubuntu archive, or selected portions of it.

Comment: Hi, as stated cannot allow port 80 (out of my control) 
Thought about the internal mirror solution myself which might be an option longer term.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could change your sources list to one of the mirrors that offer HTTPS support.

See the [entire list here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).

When you find a mirror you like, replace all instances of `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` with your chosen archive. Imagine you settle on `https://mirrors.c0urier.net/linux/ubuntu`, then do this to replace:

```
sudo sed -i 's+http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu+https://mirrors.c0urier.net/linux/ubuntu+g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now do the upgrade again.

Comment: Hi, will see if changing the sources works, although i'm not totally convinced as i think its whatever the do-release-upgrade script does to go and check for the the latest LTS release and then creates the above file i mentioned.
Thanks

Comment: So, it almost works, changing the sources.list to a valid https mirror does allow it to connect, then for some reason the do-release-upgrade decides to use the IP of the domain/url its connecting to to download the upgradetool e.g. the focal.tar.gz at this point my corporate firewall inspects the SSL connection and says "nope that ip doesn't equal the name in the cert"